# Database update notification using SignalR and Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, signalr

I'm trying to make a website using `asp.net mvc 4` and `EF 6` where I want to update the messagebox of adminpanel if any user sends him any message. I'm using `SignalR` for live notification but I'm new to `SignalR` and for some reason I don't get the updates live, I've to refresh the page to get the newly added message. Here are my codes,

**Hub Class**

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    MyProj.Models.MsgToOwner messages = new MyProj.Models.MsgToOwner();

    public void SendNotify(string username, string title, string datetimeNow)
    {
        var newName = messages.name;
        var newTitle = messages.title;
        var newTime = messages.addedtime;
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
        context.Clients.All.getNotify(newName, newTitle, newTime);
    }
}
```

**View for All Messages**

```
@{
    var MsgList = (List<MyProj.Models.MsgToOwner>)ViewBag.MsgList;
}
<body>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/LiveScript.js"></script>
    <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-messages" id="newItem">
                    @foreach (var item in MsgList)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <strong>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.title)</strong>
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted">
                                        <em>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.addedtime)</em>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div>Sent By : <strong>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)</strong></div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
</body>
```

**LiveScript.js (script for updating from SignalR)**

```
$(function () {
    var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
    chat.client.getNotify = function (username, title, datetimeNow) {
        $('#newItem').append(
            '<li><a href="#"><div><strong>' + htmlEncode(title) + '</strong><span class="pull-right text-muted"><em>' + htmlEncode(datetimeNow) + '</em></span></div><div>Sent By : <strong>' + htmlEncode(username) + '</strong></div></a></li><li class="divider"></li>');
    };
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        $('#btnSend').click(function () {
            chat.server.SendNotify($('#getName').val(), $('#getTitle').val(), $('#getDate').val());
    });
});
});
```

I must be doing something wrong here but I can't figure it out since I'm new to `SignalR`. How can I update the messagebox whenever a new message is saved in db? Any guidance will be helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: Some things I see is that inside your `Hub` you do not need to use `GetHubContext` - just call `Clients.All.getNotify` directly. But I would recomend you to call your hub method not from the client but on your Controller, exactly after you save the message into the database. There you can call `GetHubContext` to get a reference to your hub and call any client method. Also, try to enable logging to see whats signalr is doing: add it before your `start()`: `$.connection.hub.logging = true;`

Comment: @Leo, thanks for the response. But can you tell me how can I call the hub method in my controller?

Comment: You can call it from an external class (like a Controller) exactly like you are doing, get a reference to you IHubContext and call the method: `IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
        context.Clients.All.getNotify(newName, newTitle, newTime);`

Comment: put an alert in   $('#btnSend').click(function () {
            chat.server.SendNotify($('#getName').val(), $('#getTitle').val(), $('#getDate').val());
    }); and check if it is called, and also put a breakpoint in hub method